# Facebook page insights lifetime metrics doesn't return results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I'm trying to get some insights on page I own, for example `page_fans` which is stated in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/insights as having both "day" and "lifetime" periods. (This is NOT the only metric I want to get but for the sake of simplicity I'll give it as an example.)

Getting it by day works, but I only wa
nt to know the lifetime value, so instead of `period=day` I tried `period=lifetime`, and I get an empty `data` array.

This is the request I am sending:

> {page_id}/insights?fields=&metric=page_fans&period=lifetime

Note, if I change to `period=day` I get a nice object:

```
"data": [
    {
      "name": "page_fans",
      "period": "day",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 21578,
          "end_time": "2019-02-24T08:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
          "value": 21580,
          "end_time": "2019-02-25T08:00:00+0000"
        }
      ],
      "title": "Lifetime Total Likes",
      "description": "Lifetime: The total number of people who have liked your Page. (Unique Users)",
      "id": "{page_id}/insights/page_fans/day"
    }
  ],
```

Other metrics I want to get lifetime data for include:
"post_video_view_time_by_region_id", 
"post_video_views_by_distribution_type", 
"post_video_view_time_by_distribution_type", 
"post_video_view_time_by_country_id"

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? just to get the current amount of fans?

Comment: Yes, and another example is the distribution of minutes viewed per country (`post_video_view_time_by_country_id`). Basically, every query I do with "period=lifetime" fails

Comment: then why use insights for this? just use `/page-id?fields=fan_count`

Comment: Because I also want other insights like the examples I gave

Comment: then either do another api call, or just use the "day" period and take the last entry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the changelog for [v3.2](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.2#page-insights)

> **Page Insights**
>
> *These changes apply to v3.2+, and will apply to all versions on January 21, 2019.*
>
> Period parameters have been changed to **day** from **lifetime** for
>   the following metrics. The **lifetime** period parameter will return
>   an empty dataset.
>
> - page_fans
> - page_fans_city
> - page_fans_country
> - page_fans_gender_age
> - page_fans_locale

Comment: Thank you! So just to confirm, there are no more `lifetime` metrics for pages, at all, right?

Comment: Edited the post. I think that lifetime was changed only for the five metrics.

Comment: Thanks, what I meant is that those are the only `lifetime` metrics that were available to `page` (for `post` there are many more) so yeah, no more `lifetime` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use /insights?metric=page_fans&date_preset=maximum

Comment: Hi Eline. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please considering adding a reference to the api version on which this works with a link if possible. Thanks!